# Saving buffer data of AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I am playing audio from my server using AVPlayer in my application. Now I want that when it completely buffer the audio then I can save that data in the application to play it later. So how can I access buffer data and save it for later use?

Comment: I know this is an old question. However, you can find the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611488/how-to-stream-a-video-with-avurlasset-and-save-to-disk-the-cached-data/37611489#37611489

Answer (score 40):

You could supply a `resourceLoader` delegate to take over control of the resource loading process from [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer) and then supply it the data as and when it requests and becomes available. The resource loader is a property on [`AVURLAsset`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset). I've documented a full solution on my [blog](http://vombat.tumblr.com/post/86294492874/caching-audio-streamed-using-avplayer) but the main idea is to switch the protocol of your URL to something custom so AVURLAsset's resource loader requires your application's assistance in loading that URL. Then when you get the `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` callbacks, start downloading the file and try to respond to the pending requests received from those delegate callbacks as and when you have data. This will allow progressive loading/playback of the content without having to run a full blown HTTP server in your app or resorting to other complicated solutions.

Comment: Great answer! I was about to go down the route of setting up a local http server that would somewhat act as a proxy, but this solution seems way more elegant. Will definitely give it a try.

Comment: Do you know which changes I have to make to get this working for video files? For some reason the player status changes to failure. I basically just inserted a video file instead of mp3 and added an avplayerlayer. The download starts and everything looks fine, but then the player's status changes from 0 (unknown) to 2 (failure)

Comment: Nice! Have you run into the problem described here? We've got the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683567/avplayer-stalling-on-large-video-files-using-resource-loader-delegate?lq=1

Comment: the code works great for audio, but not for video :(

Comment: I know this is an old question. However, you can find the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611488/how-to-stream-a-video-with-avurlasset-and-save-to-disk-the-cached-data/37611489#37611489

Comment: Hi , Thanks for this amazing work.is there any version in Swift please , because i'm struggling to get work in Xcode with swift 4,0

Answer (score 2):

The team at Calm has open-sourced our implementation to this. It's available as a CocoaPod.  It's called `PersistentStreamPlayer`.

It acts as a resourceLoader. The big benefit over other implementations is that it does *not* require the binary data to be in memory at any point, so it supports larger files.

Features include:

- streaming of audio file, starting playback as soon as first data is available
- also saves streamed data to a file URL as soon as the buffer completes
  exposes timeBuffered, helpful for displaying buffer progress bars in the UI
- handles re-starting the audio file after the buffer stream stalls (e.g. slow network)
- simple play, pause and destroy methods (destroy clears all memory resources)
- does not keep audio file data in memory, so that it supports large files that don't fit in RAM

You can find it here: https://github.com/calmcom/PersistentStreamPlayer

Comment: it mentions "Stream audio over http, and persist the data to a local file while buffering" does it work for video aswell ?

Answer (score 1):

Easy to do...using the same url for your audio stream use NSURLConnection to get the data and save using NSFilehandler...just done it myself whilst streaming audio and saving at the same time to mp3...let me know if you need code sample...

Comment: yes,sure you can share the code for others, i had done that same thing that you just explain in the Answer and its working good.

Comment: Can we please see a code sample of this? Maybe a gist on Github?

Comment: aren't you downloading the data twice by doing that? I wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the buffer of the `AVPlayer`. Some hints: You can put previews (short versions of audios) of your audio files on your server, so that Your users could listen the previews before they download the full audio files, or you may search for custom open source audio stream players, maybe those will allow you to access the stream buffer. Good Luck!